# C# DataGridView black selection with double buffer

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to achieve transparent selection with a border in a `DataGridView`. The problem is that with `DoubleBuffer` set to `True` my row selection is black like in the picture. Turning it to `false` solve the issue but makes my grid flickering.

[image: Black row]

This is the code I used to make the red border for the selected row:

```
    private void dgv_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
            {
                int penWidth = 2;

                pen.Width = penWidth;

                int x = e.RowBounds.Left + (penWidth / 2);
                int y = e.RowBounds.Top + (penWidth / 2);
                int width = e.RowBounds.Width - penWidth;
                int height = e.RowBounds.Height - penWidth;

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also set `SelectionBackColor` to `Transparent` and `SelectionForeColor` to `Black` in dgv's `RowDefaultCellsStyle`

Is there a way to have a transparent selection in `DataGridView` while keeping `DoubleBuffer` to `True` ?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448945/datagridview-row-semi-transparent-selection-or-row-border-on-selection) the sort of thing you're after?